# Best way to run spring boot 2 rest services

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot

I am writing an app that exposes some functions via REST service.

To do this I am using Spring Boot 2, but what is the best way to put it on production environment?

Is a good idea run the jar using java?

Comment: If the answers helped you, please mark it as accepted. In case of any doubts, please feel free to ask as comments to respective answers. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer**

yes it is a good idea.

**Long answer**

Spring Boot features a plugin that prepends a service script (Unix-compatible) in the JAR file itself. That makes the JAR file executable in Unix/Linux environments and you can easily install it as a service. Excerpt from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html follows:

> To create a "fully executable" jar with Maven, use the following plugin configuration:

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <executable>true</executable>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

If packaging for Windows, the startup script isn't of much use and can be omitted. You would need to run using `java -jar ...` on windows, or install a service wrapper. Another excerpt from the Spring Boot doco:

> A Spring Boot application can be started as a Windows service by using [winsw](https://github.com/kohsuke/winsw).
>
> A ([separately maintained sample](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/spring-boot-daemon)) describes step-by-step how you can create a Windows service for your Spring Boot application.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it fully executable with below code in your pom.xml. You can run with shell script or as systemv or initd service[[Spring Boot DOC]](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html). This is the [best tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-app-as-a-service) link I have found explaining the multiple  run as service options. You might want to take a look at spring doc for [production ready features](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready.html).

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <executable>true</executable>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```